# How do I turn an array into a record / tuple / row type?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, dynamicquery

I need to execute a dynamic `insert` into a table with a variable number of columns.

Right now I'm quoting both the column names, with `quote_ident`, and the actual values, with `quote_nullable`, and then joining them with `array_to_string`:

```
for ... loop
    ...
    cols := array_append(cols, quote_ident(column_name));
    vals := array_append(vals, quote_nullable(column_value));
end loop;

execute format('insert into %s (%s) values (%s)',
    target_table,
    array_to_string(cols, ', ')
    array_to_string(vals, ', ')
);
```

It's a pattern found all over the place, including on the official documentation. But it feels a bit unclean. I'd rather pass the array of values a parameter in the `using` clause:

```
execute format('insert into %s (%s) ... $1 ...',
    target_table,
    array_to_string(cols, ', ')
) 
using vals;
```

Notice the `using vals`, which is what I'd like to achieve. But I cannot seem to be able to fill in the dots in the `insert` statement. Maybe some kind of `select ... from ...`?

More generally, how do I turn an array into a record / tuple / row type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using code very like this in production:

```
EXECUTE ( SELECT 'insert into sometable ' 
    '('||string_agg(quote_ident(p.key),',') ||
            ') values ('|| string_agg(quote_nullable(p.value),',') || ');'
            FROM each(payload) as p
            );
```

but here payload is a hstore, not a pair of arrays.

Comment: The `quote_ident` are ok, because you are composing the SQL part of the query. But I'm looking for a way to avoid all the `quote_nullable` on the values, and just pass them as an array parameter.